# vue-strap `select` component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue-strap's `select` component,
Documentation：http://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#select ,
my demo is the first example in documentation.

**my demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/kanjiushi/ne92wfxp/6/

I have 2 questions about my demo:

1、there is a placeholder `Nothing Selected` in documentation's demo.How to add it in my demo?

**my demo:**
[image]

**demo in the documentation:**
[image]

2、How to get the value of the selected item and save it in a variable?I will use it to send a ajax request.

Some help please,thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @bobbybackblech I have made a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the `:value.sync` directive. that solves both of your problems. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/ne92wfxp/7/) with the result. Here is the code also

```
<v-select :value.sync="val">
   <v-option value="1">Apple</v-option>
   <v-option value="2">Banana</v-option>
   <v-option value="3">Cherry</v-option>
   <v-option value="4">Orange</v-option>
   <v-option value="5">Grape</v-option>
</v-select>
```

Notice that I had to add a `val` data to your component.

Comment: Thanks very much!  One more thing,how to change the palceholder  "Nothing Selected " to  custom text?

Comment: `placeholder` is a property of the `v-select` component, so pass it in the template, like this `<v-select :value.sync="val" placeholder="Some placeholder">`

Comment: Notice that the call for `value` and `placeholder` properties are different

Comment: thanks again, I have another question,I add a `foreach` into this demo,like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ne92wfxp/8/  ,how to take out the `v-select` component to  reuse it?

Comment: Assuming that the `foreach`that you are talking is from a server side template, the `v-select` component should be just repeated. What I suggest is to load your server data in vue and use a [`v-for`](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for) loop